# iOS (Swift), Realm migration add a new property to store another realm object

Tags: ios, swift2, realm

I ran into a strange error while trying to update the migration scheme for an existing Realm model.  
Specifically, I try to update the model by adding a property which stores another realm object.  
However, it doesn't matter how I try (even by trying to delete the former object and replace it with the new one), realm crashes with the following error "The `RMOHomebook.general` property must be marked as being optional"

Is there any way of doing this? Why do I need to mark the property as optional since it will never be optional. 

 
Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is `RMOHomebook.general` property `Object` subclass type? RealmSwift doesn't support making optional `Object` type properties. It is the current limitation of Realm underlying storage engine.

> to-one relationships must be optional

https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#relationships

See also Realm object definitions cheatsheet. https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#cheatsheet

Comment: It's not a subclass of the container, it's an Object subclass. Ah I get it about the to one relationships and optionals. However, Realm instantiates them as nil. The better choice (or at least what I chose to do) is to add it to a List property and always work with the object at index 0. Not very neat but I guess t'will have to do. thanks!